# Drupal 6 views. How to make the views title the node title of the node id argument?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, arguments

I am using the node id as an argument in a drupal view. However, I want the title of the view to display the title of the node.

For example, I have a node with node-id 36 and title "Hello World". The views page url is "example.com/display-node/36" (36 being the node-id passed as an argument). I want the title of the page displayed as "Page: Hello World". How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to figure out answer one to this question; so here is a more detailed explanation:

1. You must have the PHP Filter module enabled (*admin/build/modules*).
2. In your page view (*admin/build/views/edit/[your view name]*) click on **header** under *Basic Settings*
3. Place the following in the text box that pops up:

   ```
   <?php
   $view = views_get_current_view();
   // [0] is first arg, [1] is second etc.
   //My first argument is a Node:Nid argument to get the node id from the url.
   $node = node_load($view->args[0]);
   drupal_set_title('Page: '. $node->title);
   ?>
   ```
4. Expand the *Input Format* section and select **PHP Code**:
5. Click *update* and the title should now display properly!

Answer (score 4):

just put %1 in the views title and that will give you the title of the current node

Comment: with an argument in use, this will use that first argument as the title. You can add text to it as needed as well.

Answer (score 2):

insert in Header views php code:

```
$node = menu_get_object();
drupal_set_title('Page: '.$node->title);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Nikos Stylianou said, if you're using the "views" module you can use %1 to get the node's title. In your case:

"Page: %1"

would output

"Page: Hello World"

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't pass args into the Title, instead I had to edit the Header and use some of Robert Fleming's suggestions to get the relevant arguments parsed in as an h1.  Unfortunately I couldn't set the page title.

Comment: You might need to use the module page_title. If not you're not already using it, it's crucial for proper SEO

Answer (score 0):

To the answers from Nikos Stylianou and Tivie I would also add that you should use contextual filters to get the node ID from the view's url.

Under Advanced:
Contextual Filters -> Add -> Content:Nid -> Provide default value -> Content ID from URL.